# How to really unit test Symfony forms?

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

The following example comes from the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/unit_testing.html#the-basics):

```php
use AppBundle\Form\Type\TestedType;
use AppBundle\Model\TestObject;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;

class TestedTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = array(
            'test' => 'test',
            'test2' => 'test2',
        );

        $form = $this->factory->create(TestedType::class);

        $object = TestObject::fromArray($formData);

        // submit the data to the form directly
        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
}
```

However, with a real unit testing approach, the test should only contain an individual class as a [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html), everything else should be [Test Doubles](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html) like stubs, mock objects...

**How should we unit test a Symfony form using Test Doubles like mock objects?**

We could assume a simple form class:

```php
class TestedType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'First name',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'John Doe',
                ],
            ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is rather old but is unanswered and I stumbled upon it while being recently confronted with the same concern.

> How should we unit test a Symfony form using Test Doubles like mock objects?

We usually test the result of a single method but in the case of *buildForm* method, the only test we can write with a simple form type is the **interaction** with the *FormBuilderInterface* instance passed as parameter.

```
// Imports and PhpDoc annotations skipped for brievety
public class TestedTypeTest  extends TestCase
{
    private $systemUnderTest;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->systemUnderTest = new TestedType();
    }

    /**
     * Tests that form is correctly build according to specs
     */
    public function testBuildForm(): void
    {
        $formBuilderMock = $this->createMock(FormBuilderInterface::class);
        $formBuilderMock->expects($this->atLeastOnce())->method('add')->willReturnSelf();

        // Passing the mock as a parameter and an empty array as options as I don't test its use
        $this->systemUnderTest->buildForm($formBuilderMock, []);
    }
}
```

So it's a pretty basic unit test properly speaking, testing your class in isolation.

Don't make the same mistake I did and don't forget to call *willReturnSelf* method as *add* is a **chainable method** ([fluent interface pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)).

You can start from here and refine your test, tying it more to implementation with

```
// Tests number of calls to add method, in my case, 2
$formBuilderMock->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('add')->willReturnSelf();
```

or

```
// Tests number of calls AND parameters successively passed
$formBuilderMock->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('add')->withConsecutive(
    [$this->equalTo('field_1'), $this->equalTo(TextType::class)],
    [$this->equalTo('field_2'), $this->equalTo(TextType::class)]
);
```

I think you get the point... There, your tests are tied to implementation details, forcing you to change them as soon as you change your code : its your call to change the granularity of your tests, depending on your context.

---

**Sidenotes**

As you're not specifying any versions of Symfony and PhpUnit, know that my example use following versions:

- Symfony 4.1
- PhpUnit 7.5

**Questions read while answering about testing behavior**

[Do mocks break the "test the interface, not the implementation" mantra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808962/do-mocks-break-the-test-the-interface-not-the-implementation-mantra)
[What's the difference between faking, mocking, and stubbing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346372/whats-the-difference-between-faking-mocking-and-stubbing)